# asp.net how to hide code in dll files

Tags: asp.net, computer-science

Is there any way to protect the code written in the cs files?  Also for the database?

We designed a website and we're considering publishing it and we have to deliver the project as a college project, but we want to protect the code so we can secure it in case we publish it.

We are already considering publishing the site and then giving them its url but it's our last option.

**What can we do in this case besides publishing the site?**

Thanks :)

Comment: Typically, IIS won't serve .cs, .config, or .dll files.  What's your concern here?  It also won't show any of your server-side script in your .aspx to an end user.

Comment: oh, what i meant is: is there anyway to give them the project files (design files and everything on CD) so they can test it without being able to access the cs code and the database structure

Comment: Give them the necessary files (images, markup, JS and CSS files, DLLs) and they can put it on a server and look at it that way.  But if it's a college project, I would expect your instructor would want to see the code as well, wouldn't they?

Comment: You might also want to check if the university/college has legal rights to all your coursework. Some institutes actually own all code you write if you are enrolled with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compile your project into a single dll file, you have to use the **Publish Web Site** function of Visual Studio. I use **Visual Studio Express 2012 (version 11)**, so if you don't have this version, then there could be slight differences.

1. Click on the "BUILD" menu, then select Publish Web Site
2. Create a new Profile if you haven't done so.
3. Click on 'Connection' on the left side menu of the window, and choose File System to save it on a folder on your computer
4. Click 'Settings'. Open up File Publish Options and select the following: [image]
5. Click on the 'Configure' link of the second option in the above screenshot. This will open the following window. Here you can play around with the merge settings. I've tried the 3rd and last option on a test website, and the output was similar. The text (testwebsite) in the textbox is for the name of the DLL file. 
   [image]
6. Click 'Publish'